# Why Firefox alert me about HTTPs "Untrusted" Connection on Positivessl - Comodo certificate?

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, https

For my new startUp I got a SSL certificate from Comodo.com. I did all the painful process and finally I was able to implement it on my AWS server (I'm running MEAN Stack). Now when someone visit my website using Firefox the got this error:

> Technical Details
>
> Invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided. 
>   (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

But obviously I don't want my users to receive that warning.

I thought that maybe the server was delivering some file by the regular http and I couldn't find any non-https content, so I imagine I'm ok about that issue (maybe not)

This is my first time using a SSL certificate and maybe I'm doing it wrong. Please if you can help me out will be great. Thanks

Here is the image:

[image]

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s111/sh/a4bd8f33-8dba-47ae-b6d9-d1793acb8c64/1682676a05ebebddb8ed14a112df9d94

Answer (score 1):

Although you *did* install a SSL certificate, you did not include any additional certificates that are necessary to build a trust path. See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=phrecordr.com

About the trust path, the SSL client has some root certificates that are stored. When you buy a certificate **C** from some CA, they might use some intermediate certficate (let's call this **B**) that is signed by the root CA **A**. If you only provide the certificate **C** to the client, then they will not be able to establish a trust path from **A** to **C**. To fix this, append the certificate **B** to your certificate **C**.

The exact details depend on the SSL server that you are using, consult their documentation for the specifics.

Comment: Thanks @Lekenstey, I received these files from PositiveSSL: `mydomain_com.ca-bundle` and `mydomain_com.crt`. I am using NodeJS/ExpressJS. I took a look at the the documentation but I'm not an expert and is taking me hard times, what should I change?  [http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_server_listen_handle_callback](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_server_listen_handle_callback). This is my NodeJS code `var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, pfx:authorityChain.ca-bundle};`

Comment: @lito If I'm not mistaken, you should key + cert *or* pfx, not both. If you have a single file (for `pfx`) with keys and certs concatenated, you should append the CA bundle to that file. Otherwise, append the file to the cert. I suggest to keep the keys and certs separate anyway so you can set very tigh permissions on the keys.

Comment: Probably easiest to just supply in the ca field: `
  var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(cert),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(chainCert)
  };` 
ca can also be an array of certs if you have multiple.

Answer (score 0):

June 2014:

For NodeJS and ExpressJS

This is the configuration I used and it working fine after banging my head on the wall for some days. I use Express 3.4 (I think is the same for Express 4.0)

```
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('helpers/sslcert/key.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('helpers/sslcert/csr.pem', 'utf8');

files = ["COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt",
         "COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt",
         "AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt"
        ];

ca = (function() {
  var _i, _len, _results;

  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    file = files[_i];
    _results.push(fs.readFileSync("helpers/sslcert/" + file));
  }
  return _results;
})();

var credentials = {ca:ca, key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

// process.env.PORT : Heroku Config environment
var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('Express HTTPS server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

// redirect all http requests to https
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://mydomain.com', req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

Then I redirected the 80 and 443 ports:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4000
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

As you can see after checking my certifications I have 4 [0,1,2,3]:

> openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 -showcerts | grep "^ "

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-134:~$ openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 -showcerts | grep "^ "
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=mydomain.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 8FDEAEE92ED20742.....3E7D80F93226142DD
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: C9E4AB966E41A85EEB7....4D73C67088E1503C52A9353C8584E94
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 7c c8 36 80 95 4d 4c 47-d8 e3 ca 2e 70 a5 8f ac   |.6..MLG....p...
    0010 - 90 bd 4a 26 ef f7 d6 bc-4a b3 dd 8f f6 13 53 e9   ..J&..........S.
    0020 - f7 49 c6 48 44 26 8d ab-a8 72 29 c8 15 73 f5 79   .I.HD&.......s.y
    0030 - ca 79 6a ed f6 b1 7f 8a-d2 68 0a 52 03 c5 84 32   .yj........R...2
    0040 - be c5 c8 12 d8 f4 36 fa-28 4f 0e 00 eb d1 04 ce   ........(.......
    0050 - a7 2b d2 73 df a1 8b 83-23 a6 f7 ef 6e 9e c4 4c   .+.s...........L
    0060 - 50 22 60 e8 93 cc d8 ee-42 22 56 a7 10 7b db 1e   P"`.....B.V..{..
    0070 - 0a ad 4a 91 a4 68 7a b0-9e 34 01 ec b8 7b b2 2f   ..J......4...{./
    0080 - e8 33 f5 a9 48 11 36 f8-69 a6 7a a6 22 52 b1 da   .3..H...i....R..
    0090 - 51 18 ed c4 d9 3d c4 cc-5b d7 ff 92 4e 91 02 9e   .....=......N...
    Start Time: 140...549
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Good luck!
PD: if u want more answers please check: http://www.benjiegillam.com/2012/06/node-dot-js-ssl-certificate-chain/

Comment: You should not include the root CA. It is no use (it does not help in building a trust path) and enlarges the initial handshake size. Please test your setup with the ssllabs tool I linked above.